# How to use IMPORTRANGE with a variable range-string pulled from a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange

I'm trying to create a user friendly sheet where data is pulled from a different Google Sheets based on input from the user. So far I have this working:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(C40,"2016 Data!W2:W13")
```

Where the user inputs the `spreadsheet_key` into C40 (i.e. - `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcdef1234`)

My problem is that I would also like a variable `range_string` (i.e. - `2016 Data!W2:W13`) where the column name, i.e. - `W`, is the variable that the user adjusts. I've been able to get this far where user inputs `W` into cell B41 with this function:

```
="""2016 Data!"&B41&"2:"&B41&"13"""
```

to generate:

```
"2016 Data!W2:W13"
```

in cell C41. When I reference this cell in the IMPORTRANGE function, like this

```
=IMPORTRANGE(C40,C41)
```

I get this error:

> `#REF!` - Cannot find range or sheet for imported range.

How can I get IMPORTRANGE to recognize the `range_string` from cell C41?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your referring to the cell where the regular text is you don't need to add the additional `""` around the `="""2016 Data!"&B41&"2:"&B41&"13"""`

just simply enter: `="2016 Data!"&B41&"2:"&B41&"13"`

You only add the additional quotes when your directly entering that data into the formula, not when its via the cell reference